# What are the specifications of this Zenith bush airplane's gear and tires?

Tags: landing-gear, tire, zenith-aircraft-company

[image: Zenith's bush airplane]

I would like to know the name (if any) and the specifications of Zenith's bush airplane? I would like to know the size, the diameter, the maximum load, bearing number/type, and so on. Seems that the front gear and the main are different in spec.

Comment: It's a [Zenith STOL CH 701](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zenith_STOL_CH_701). See also [here](http://www.zenith.aero/profiles/blogs/stol-competition-winners) and the links on that page. Also [here](http://zenithair.com/stolch701/7-design-gear.html) for the gear.

Comment: The two links are good. But unfortunately I can not see there the gear specs.